# Java PhysX Binding?

Tags: java, physics, physx

Is there a PhysX binding for Java of any kind? I looked around a bit and saw this: http://jphysx.com/, but I got some weird Russian error thing. Even a plain old powerful physics engine with java support would work.

Comment: Does searching for "java physics engine" turn up nothing useful? Also, "port" is the wrong term for this, but searching for "java physx binding" doesn't seem to turn up anything, so PhysX itself doesn't look feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't tell you how well it works, but have you seen the google code project [physX4java](http://code.google.com/p/physx4java/)?

Comment: Doesn't seem to turn up anything useful, it seems like an abandoned project.

Comment: It very well _may_ be dead; but, it does have a "demo" section in the source code (which seems to never been built into a release).  Check out http://code.google.com/p/physx4java/source/browse/#svn%2Fphysx4java2%2Fsrc%2Fnet%2Fphysx4java%2Fdemos%2Fsimple to see if what is in the dead project is "good enough" for your needs.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Thanks!